# If-statement for 20 years from the Current Date

Tags: excel, vba, date, if-statement, named-ranges

I am trying to:

1) Set 2 variable in date format.
 2) 1 variable cannot be more then twenty years from the current date.
 3) Those variables then set another variable's cell values which are set to a numerical format.

The macro is not functional and I am getting issues trying to code the worksheet as worksheet.

```
Sub Date_Check()

'Coding Variables

Dim WB As ThisWorkbook
Dim Test_Data As Sheet1
Dim statedate as String
statedate = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
Dim enddate as string
enddate = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
Dim todaydate as date
'Coverage date is enddate-statedate cell 
Dim CvgDate as Range
Set CvgDate(26) = enddate.value - statedate.value
Dim jj as Integer
Dim x as boolean
x = True

'set the ranges as the last cell to contain values

With Worksheet("TestData")
    .Range("V2:V"). Offset(-1,0).xldown.Value2 = startdate
    .Range("W2:W").Offset(-1,0).xldown.Value2 = enddate
    .Range("FutureDate").Format(Date, "yyyy") = True

    ' Error!

    ' I am getting an argument not option error when trying to set futureyear.
    'Create function that will check if range is 20 years within today's date.
    FutureYear = 20  < DateSerial(Year, 1)
    .Range("enddate").Offset(-1, 0).Select =x
    .Cell.Number = "mm/dd/yyyy"

    'Create an if statement using fuction
    If Range("enddate").Cell <> = FutureYear Then
        MsgBox "Please check that the end reporting date is within 20 years from today's date!" 
    End If

    'Ensure that enddate meets criteria before being put in numerical format
    .Range("Cvgdate").Offset(-1,0).Select
    .Selection.NumberFormat = "jj"   

End With
```

Any suggestions are helpful but I am focused on ensuring that the enddate variable is within 20 years of the current date.

Comment: It would be helpful to know **what** error you're getting, on **which** line of code.

Comment: @ Mistella I will write error right beneath the code that is giving me an error.

Comment: You should look into how `DateSerial` works. I know it requires three arguments (year, month, day) but am not sure of the order. Also, is `FutureYear` supposed to resolve to either `True` or `False`? Because, I think that's what it'll do.

Comment: I was originally trying to use a date variable (which has the current day value) to ensure that the compared date (enddate) is no more then 20 years in the future.

Comment: I'm trying to think through this to help out, but I just can't tell what you are trying to do in this code. `.Range("V2:V").Offset(-1,0).xldown.Value2 = startdate` is nonsense. How is that not erroring out?  You declare the variable "stardate", then set the variable "Statedate" then set this range's value to the variable "startdate". Those are all different. If I had to guess I would say that you have a startdate and an enddate on your workbook and you are wanting to compare them to get a duration, but only if the enddate isn't 20 years or more into the future?

Comment: @ JNevill Thank you for the help. You are absolutely right, I am am using relying on select way too much. So I need the entire column (maybe a long variable instead for row and column?). The sheet itself that I am using has quite a few macros on it, and I am having problems coding it regularly, so I am wondering if that is why.

Comment: @SomedayI'llbegreatatVBA You should also consider adding `Option Explicit` at the top of each code module. This will force you to declare each variable you use. A little tiresome to fix, if you're adding to a module with lots of code, but really helpful in the long run as it helps prevent typos from slipping in unnoticed.

Comment: Your starting from a good place here. Your code is all over the place and there are variables declares and never used and misspelled (OPTION EXPLICIT will help like @mistella suggests). But... it's headed in the right direction. I took a crack, simplifying your code after making some pretty big assumptions about what you are trying to do. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really struggling to understand what you are trying to do given the code that is posted. I can't imagine it making it all the way to the line that is throwing the error without erroring well before that.

Just the same, here is a brief rewrite that I think is close to what you are trying to do. Namely, Get two dates from the worksheet in columns `V` and `W` and set those dates to a variable. Then compare the `enddate` from column `W` to current date and throw a message box up if it's more than 20 years from now.

```
Sub Date_Check()
    Dim startdate as date
    Dim enddate as date

    With Worksheet("TestData")
        'Set startdate and end date getting it form the last populated row in each column
        startdate = .Range("V2").End(xlDown).Value
        enddate = .Range("W2").End(xlDown).Value

        'Check to see if enddate is more than 20 years from now (ignoring leap years)
        If enddate - Date > 365*20 Then
            MsgBox "Please check that the end reporting date is within 20 years from today's date!" 
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```

This doesn't take into account your `cvgdate` range, but that is set incorrectly and you never really do anything with it besides change the number format.

A couple of pointers:

1. If you are dealing with a date in a variable, then declare the variable as a date. String dates are of the devil. You can't subtract strings, and you can't compare string dates with other string dates without substringing yourself into a corner.
2. Above all of your code in your module put `Option Explicit` this will cause your VBE to throw an error if you try to use a variable that is not declared catching spelling mistakes as they happen.
3. Don't `.Select` or `.Activate`. That's for humans, not code. The only exception is if, at the end of your code, you want to set a particular worksheet or cell as selected. Then a nice little `Sheet1.Range("A1").Select` so your user is set up at the top of the worksheet is totally cool.